# how to use threads and sleep() functionality with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, thread-sleep, worker-thread

I am trying to learn `node.js` after `python` and trying to thread an infinitely running process in the background with a 2 minute `sleep()`.

---

***main.js***

```
const TeleBot = require("telebot");
const fun = require('fun.js');

fun(); //function I want to thread

const bot = new TeleBot({
  token: "Bot_Token",
});

bot.on(["/start", "/hello"], (msg) => {
  bot.sendMessage(msg.from.id, `Hello ${msg.chat.username}`);
});

bot.start();
```

---

I saw some people using this `sleep()` function but it didn't work

***fun.js***

```
module.exports = async function fun()
{
    while (1) {
        await sleep(10000);
        console.log("I ran");
    }
}
```

**Error:** `sleep is not defined`

So, I tried this

```
const sleep = (waitTimeInMs) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, waitTimeInMs));
module.exports = async function fun()
{
    while (1) {
        await sleep(10000);
        console.log("I ran");
    }
}
```

It works but is this a good practice and ok to use? Also, can someone tell me how to use `worker-threads` for this.

Comment: *trying to thread an infinitely running process in the background with a 2 minute sleep()*.  That's your main problem.  node.js is an event driven environment.  You should be rethinking your problem into an event driven model.  While nodejs has threads, nodejs will perform better if you convert to an event driven architecture.  If you want help with that, then please show the actual code that you think you need to thread and we can offer ideas about how to rethink as event driven.

Comment: FYI, `await sleep(10000);` where sleep immediately returns a promise does not block the current thread so it does not need threading in order to do other things along with it.  That's an event-driven sleep implementation that doesn't need threads.

Comment: So, i think I had it all wrong i suppose. Okay I will try to learn more before jumping in node.js thanx @jfriend00